# авторизация в вк nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, express

Всем привет!
Подскажите простой способ авторизации сайта на node.js + виджет авторизации вк.

Курил мануал вк, нужно получить список друзей авторизованного, но увы если запрос кидает сервер - кричит что нет доступа.

Answer (score 0):

Passport.js - самое надёжное, простое, лучшее и эффективное.
https://github.com/stevebest/passport-vkontakte